# Clicking an element that is beneath another element

Tags: wpf

I've got the following setup:

A rectangle say 100 pixels wide which expands to 200 pixels wide on MouseEnter. On MouseLeave, it goes back down to 100 pixels. On MouseEnter, it also sets the visibility of a canvas containing some buttons to Visible. This canvas and its buttons sit underneath the 200 pixel-wide rectangle, and can't be clicked.

Is there any way to be able to click these buttons?

It's set up more or less like this:

```
<Rectangle Name="hover" Panel.ZIndex="2" Width="100" MouseEnter="dostuff" MouseLeave="dostuff2" />

<Canvas Visibility="Hidden" Name="buttons" Panel.ZIndex="1">
<Button ... />
<Button ... />
<Button ... />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `hover.IsHitTestVisible = False` this may help you..

Comment: I'll vote yes on that. I think that will probably affect your MouseLeave event, but without custom HitTest'ing, I think that's about your best bet. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx for more info and see the related "HitTesting in the Visual Layer" if you need to go down that route.

Comment: I tried IsHitTestVisible, but the issue there was that upon setting it, it immediately forces MouseExit to fire, since you are essentially exiting the object when it becomes untestable (which then sets the visibility of my target canvas to Hidden). I'll look into the link, though, maybe something there can help.